# using javascript and html forms to calulate

Tags: javascript, forms

Please can anyone please help me to code a Retail Space Cost Calculator for a shopping complex / mall on a webpage using a HTML form and a Javascript function. I want the user to enter a value for retail space in square feet find its total cost in US dollars. The cost per square feet of retail space is $20.

Thanks in advance,
john richards.

Comment: multiply space with $20 ie `cost = 20 * space`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a small example, using jquery (but you can use javascript as well)

```
var space = $("#txtSpace").val();
if (Number(space))
{
    $("#txtPrice").val((Number(space)*20).toString());
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cnqjn/

With pure javascript:
http://jsfiddle.net/cnqjn/1/